# ColdFusion SMS Gateway Instance problem

Tags: coldfusion, sms-gateway, event-gateway

I am having a strange problem with my SMS Gateway. The SMPP connection to the external gateway is fine, and outgoing messages are never a problem.

The problem is to do with my incoming.cfc - the gateway instance points to "incoming.cfc" and that file is set up to send an auto reply to the incoming message and add some details to a database. Simple and it works as tested.

Every couple of days though the incoming messages stop getting added to the database, and the auto reply messages don't get generated. The log files indicate that (although no changes have been made to either the incoming.cfc file or any other files or configuration settings) we have somehow "switched back" to an earlier version of the incoming.cfc file - I can tell this because the wording of the return message in the logs matches this earlier version.

I have read Adobe documentation that says the gateway will use whatever incoming.cfc it is pointed to and you don't need to refresh the event gateway instance if you change the cfc - even though the old cfc has been deleted off the server entirely and the new one not changed - when the problem occurs (every other day) an instance refresh appears to fix it.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Thanks for listening!

Simon

Comment: just some wild guesses - do you have trusted cache turned on? is your application timing out?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions - don't believe we are timing out and trusted caching is turned off as it is a shared hosting environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your `cfc` from `incoming.cfc` to `incoming2.cfc`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I have changed the name - but the problem perssits - I am going to try clearing out the classes folder next.

Comment: A quick update - cleared out the classes folder - problem persists. Have seen a suggestion to lower the ping interval so will try that and report back as well!